# Interview - Find magnitude pole in an array

Tags: algorithm

Magnitude Pole: An element in an array whose left hand side elements are lesser than or equal to it and whose right hand side element are greater than or equal to it.

**example input**

```
3,1,4,5,9,7,6,11
```

**desired output**

```
4,5,11
```

I was asked this question in an interview and I have to return the index of the element and only return the first element that met the condition.

**My logic**

> 1. Take two MultiSet (So that we can consider duplicate as well), one for right hand side of the element and one for left hand side of the
>      element(the pole).
> 2. Start with 0th element and put rest all elements in the "right set".
> 3. Base condition if this 0th element is lesser or equal to all element on "right set" then return its index.
> 4. Else put this into "left set" and start with element at index 1.
> 5. Traverse the Array and each time pick the maximum value from "left set" and minimum value from "right set" and compare.
> 6. At any instant of time for any element all the value to its left are in the "left set" and value to its right are in the "right set"

**Code**

```
int magnitudePole (const vector<int> &A) {  
   multiset<int> left, right;        
   int left_max, right_min;          
   int size = A.size();
   for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
       right.insert(A[i]);
   right_min = *(right.begin()); 
   if(A[0] <= right_min)
       return 0;
   left.insert(A[0]);
   for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
       right.erase(right.find(A[i]));
       left_max = *(--left.end());
       if (right.size() > 0)
           right_min = *(right.begin());
       if (A[i] > left_max && A[i] <= right_min)
           return i;
       else
           left.insert(A[i]);
   }
   return -1;
}
```

**My questions**

> - I was told that my logic is incorrect, I am not able to understand why this logic is incorrect (though I have checked for some cases and
>     it is returning right index)
> - For my own curiosity how to do this without using any set/multiset in O(n) time.

Comment: The description you give of the logic behind your algorithm seems a little imprecise about the details (when do you erase from the RHS? when do you compare? when do you insert in the LHS?) but in general the idea seems correct, as it is basically a brute force search that uses multisets to help with the bookkeeping.

Comment: Actually it was online test so I coded it first but when they replied that it was wrong so I just told them that this is what I did. So may be my algorithm is not in detail but they judge based on the algorithm in the code.

Comment: does 4 is not a Magnitude Pole?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For an O(n) algorithm:

1. Count the largest element from n[0] to n[k] for all k in [0, length(n)), save the answer in an array maxOnTheLeft. This costs O(n);
2. Count the smallest element from n[k] to n[length(n)-1] for all k in [0, length(n)), save the answer in an array minOnTheRight. This costs O(n);
3. Loop through the whole thing and find any n[k] with maxOnTheLeft <= n[k] <= minOnTheRight. This costs O(n).

And you code is (at least) wrong here:

```
if (A[i] > left_max && A[i] <= right_min) // <-- should be >= and <=
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer. Your algorithm is correct, just now I realised yes I missed that "=" but as per the interviewer my algorithm is incorrect :(

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: Why? O(N)+O(N)+...O(N) any constant times = O(N).

Comment: Finding the largest element from `n[0]` to `n[k]` for any given `k` is O(n). Doing this for all k in `[0, length(n)]` (which is `== n`) will be O(n²). Wouldn't it?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Just do it incrementally would make it linear.

Answer (score 3):

- Create two bool[N] called NorthPole and SouthPole (just to be humorous.
- step forward through A[]tracking maximum element found so far, and set SouthPole[i] true if A[i] > Max(A[0..i-1])
- step backward through A[] and set NorthPole[i] true if A[i] < Min(A[i+1..N-1)
- step forward through NorthPole and SouthPole to find first element with both set true.

O(N) in each step above, as visiting each node once, so O(N) overall.

Answer (score 3):

Java implementation:

```
Collection<Integer> magnitudes(int[] A) {
    int length = A.length;
    // what's the maximum number from the beginning of the array till the current position
    int[] maxes = new int[A.length];
    // what's the minimum number from the current position till the end of the array
    int[] mins = new int[A.length];

    // build mins
    int min = mins[length - 1] = A[length - 1];
    for (int i = length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (A[i] < min) {
            min = A[i];
        }
        mins[i] = min;
    }

    // build maxes
    int max = maxes[0] = A[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        if (A[i] > max) {
            max = A[i];
        }
        maxes[i] = max;
    }

    Collection<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    // use them to find the magnitudes if any exists
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (A[i] >= maxes[i] && A[i] <= mins[i]) {
            // return here if first one only is needed
            result.add(A[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems perfectly correct (didn't check the implementation, though) and can be implemented to give an O(n) time algorithm! Nice job thinking in terms of sets.

Your right set can be implemented as a stack which supports a min, and the left set can be implemented as a stack which supports a max and this gives an O(n) time algorithm.

Having a stack which supports max/min is a well known interview question and can be done so each operation (push/pop/min/max is O(1)).

To use this for your logic, the pseudo code will look something like this

```
foreach elem in a[n-1 to 0]
    right_set.push(elem)

while (right_set.has_elements()) {
   candidate = right_set.pop();
   if (left_set.has_elements() && left_set.max() <= candidate <= right_set.min()) {
       break;
   } else if (!left.has_elements() && candidate <= right_set.min() {
        break;
   }
   left_set.push(candidate);
}

return candidate
```

Comment: Yeah at that time I forgot that I can use stack.

Comment: @JackSparrow: Implementation details :-). I really like the way you thought about this. It has some maturity to it!

Comment: @JackSparrow: It might be that your implementation is wrong. Are they claiming that the logic you have is incorrect? Did they say what the flaw was?

Comment: @JackSparrow, btw, I just looked at your implementation. It seems like you are assuming right_min is at the beginning and left_max is at the end. That is incorrect. You need to walk through the whole set in your implementation.

Comment: Actually they were telling my logic is incorrect because I asked them on mail what went wrong so they replied that my logic is incorrect and I actually need three loops one from start to end , one from end to start and one to filter out the result. I explain them that as we have to return first value that satisfies this cond so I don't need to filter out any result.

Comment: @JackSparrow: The logic they might be referring to might be the logic in the code, not the logic you wrote in the question here?

Comment: Yes but I am using Multiset so minimum will always be at beginning and max at end. (C++).

Comment: @JackSparrow: I see. Did your algorithm fail any test cases?

Comment: I gave my test on codility so the input that were present in that ran fine but as per them It is failing in long input. May be this is because instead of ">=" i used ">" while comparing to left_min

Comment: Correction it is "left_max"

Comment: @JackSparrow: I see a potential problem with right.erase. Is it possible it deletes all of them? (Never mind, just checked the documentation)

Comment: I dont think so because it depends on length of the loop and the length of the loop is same as the element in the set

Comment: @JackSparrow: Did you try again after the >= <= suggestion by one of the other answers? Also, by failing, does it mean it is giving wrong results? Or is it timing out?

Comment: I tried and It is working fine that's why I was curious that what went wrong. I guess they didn't check my algorithm and they randomly replied that my algorithm is incorrect.

Comment: @JackSparrow: Even the long input works, then? Great! Good luck!

Comment: didn't check the long input :( will do it for sure. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 1):

I saw this problem on Codility, solved it with Perl:

```
sub solution {
        my (@A) = @_;            

        my ($max, $min) = ($A[0], $A[-1]);
        my %candidates;

        for my $i (0..$#A) {
                if ($A[$i] >= $max) {
                        $max = $A[$i];
                        $candidates{$i}++;
                }
        }
        for my $i (reverse 0..$#A) {
                if ($A[$i] <= $min) {
                        $min = $A[$i];
                        return $i if $candidates{$i};
                }
        }
        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following code? I think its efficiency is not good in the worst case, but it's expected efficiency would be good.

```
    int getFirstPole(int* a, int n)
{
    int leftPole = a[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(a[j] >= leftPole)
        {
            int j = i;
            for(; j < n; j++)
            {
                if(a[j] < a[i])
                {
                    i = j+1;  //jump the elements between i and j                   
                    break;
                }
                else if (a[j] > a[i])
                    leftPole = a[j];
            }
            if(j == n) // if no one is less than a[i] then return i
                return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create array of ints called `mags`, and int variable called `maxMag`.
2. For each element in source array check if element is greater or equal to `maxMag`.
3. If is: add element to mags array and set `maxMag = element`.
4. If isn't: loop through mags array and remove all elements lesser.

Result: array of magnitude poles

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, I am having my own solution in C# which I have given below, read the comments to understand my approach.

```
public int MagnitudePoleFinder(int[] A)
{
    //Create a variable to store Maximum Valued Item i.e. maxOfUp
    int maxOfUp = A[0];

    //if list has only one value return this value
    if (A.Length <= 1) return A[0];

    //create a collection for all candidates for magnitude pole that will be found in the iteration
    var magnitudeCandidates = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();

    //add the first element as first candidate
    var a = A[0];
    magnitudeCandidates.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0, a));

    //lets iterate
    for (int i = 1; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
        a = A[i];
        //if this item is maximum or equal to all above items ( maxofUp will hold max value of all the above items)
        if (a >= maxOfUp)
        {
            //add it to candidate list
            magnitudeCandidates.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, a));
            maxOfUp = a;
        }
        else
        {
            //remote all the candidates having greater values to this item
            magnitudeCandidates = magnitudeCandidates.Except(magnitudeCandidates.Where(c => c.Value > a)).ToList();
        }
    }
    //if no candidate return -1
    if (magnitudeCandidates.Count == 0) return -1;
    else
        //return value of first candidate
        return magnitudeCandidates.First().Key;
}
```