# Find nth number that doesn't exist in a set

Tags: algorithm, set

Given a set of skipped numbers I need to find an Nth number that doesn't exist in the set.
Example:

Given a set [1, 4, 5] some results:

For N = 1 result 0

For N = 2 result 2 (because 1 is skipped)

For N = 3 result 3 (because 1 is skipped)

For N = 4 result 6 (because 1,4,5 get skipped)

This should work for fairly large N, so the straightforward solution doesnt quite cut it sadly =(

Comment: what do you mean by "the straightforward solution?" what solution do you think is too slow?

Comment: This will be always O(n), because you have to loop through all elements. No way to skip some.

Comment: @fedorqui But the *n* in your comment is different from the *N* in the question

Comment: If the input list is an ordered one and the number of elements is given, then you can come up with a solution which has a better complexity than O(N). Otherwise @fedorqui's comment is valid.

Comment: Thats basically what I'm doing:

1) order the set

2) find the space between adjecent numbers (e.g. 4-1 = 2)

3) continue gathering those bit of space until their sum is >=N

Comment: @CahitGungor You can certainly do better than O(N). You can however not do better than O(k), where k is the size of the input list

Comment: @NiklasB. I meant input size with N. If the array is sorted and you know the size of the array, you can achieve logarithmic complexity.

Comment: @Dracony there is an easy solution, which is to create a list of numbers that don't exist between min and max values in the input list, as periods to save space, then getting the Nth missing number would take O(1) time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to build up an auxiliary array telling you, for each index in the array, the number of values below it that are missing. For example, in this array:

```
1 4 5 9 13  (Array A)
```

this array would be

```
1 4 5 9 13  (Array A)
1 3 3 6 9   (Array B)
```

You can fill in Array B in time O(n) using the following approach:

- B[0] = A[0] (do you see why?)
- B[n + 1] = B[n] + A[n + 1] - A[n] - 1. This looks cryptic, but is actually pretty straightforward. The number of total values missing before position n + 1 is given by the number of values missing before position n (that's B[n]), plus the number of elements missing between positions A[n + 1] and A[n]. That value is A[n + 1] - A[n] - 1.

There's an important observation you can make now: for any position i, the value of A[i] is given by B[i] + i. (Check this out above). Why is this? Well, for any position i, the number of numbers missing below it is B[i]. There's also i numbers before it, which means that the total number of values less than it is B[i] + i.

Now that you have this, you can answer queries of the form "what's the kth missing number?" in time O(log n) by using the following algorithm:

- Do a binary search in the B array (note that it's sorted!) to find the first value strictly greater than k.
- If that entry occurs at position 0, then the answer is k. The reason for this is that you're looking for the kth smallest missing number in the array, and k was smaller than the first entry in the array. Therefore, the number you want is k itself.
- If that entry occurs elsewhere (say, position x), then you know x ≠ 0, so there's some position right before it, which is position x - 1. Since B[x - 1] ≤ k, you know that the value you want must come between A[x - 1] and A[x]. If you then subtract out B[x] from k, you get back the index of the missing number between A[x - 1] and A[x]. Therefore, your missing number is A[x - 1] + k - B[x - 1] + 1.

For example, let's take the earlier array:

```
1 4 5 9 13  (Array A)
1 3 3 6 9   (Array B)
```

Suppose we want the 5th smallest missing value. Doing our binary search finds this spot:

```
1 4 5 9 13  (Array A)
1 3 3 6 9   (Array B)
      ^
```

Backing up one spot takes us here:

```
1 4 5 9 13  (Array A)
1 3 3 6 9   (Array B)
    ^
```

The answer should be A[i] + k - B[i] + 1. This is 5 - 3 + 5 + 1 = 8. This is correct:

- The 0th missing element is 0
- The 1st missing element is 2
- The 2nd missing element is 3
- The 3rd missing element is 6
- The 4th missing element is 7
- The 5th missing element is 8.

Let's do another: suppose we want the 6th. The binary search takes us here:

```
1 4 5 9 13  (Array A)
1 3 3 6 9   (Array B)
        ^
```

Back up a spot:

```
1 4 5 9 13  (Array A)
1 3 3 6 9   (Array B)
      ^
```

We want A[i] + k - B[i] + 1 = 9 + 6 - 6 + 1 = 10. That's indeed the correct answer.

Overall, this is O(n) preprocessing, and queries can be solved in time O(log n) each.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice idea. Seems similar to solving the "find the magnetic pole of the array" problem

Comment: You should add O(nlogn) complexity for sorting before hands. @Dracony states that he orders it first. `O(nlogn) **sort**  + O(n) **preprocessing** + k O(logn) **query**` where  **k** is the number of searches on the resulted set. If k is fairly large than the algorithm performs well.

Comment: @CahitGungor Oh, I assumed the array was already sorted. If it's not, you're right that we need to factor that in!

Comment: @Dracony I'm not familiar with that problem - can you provide a link?

Comment: Well sorting would still be amortized since the set would rarely change, amortized O(logn) is still awesome.

Magnitude pole problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397637/interview-find-magnitude-pole-in-an-array

Basically it requires biulding of similar auxilary arrays